# Need help in Python for JSON data scraping

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, automation

I am using the below code for scraping data from a website. but I am facing `key error: 0`

Kindly tell me the problems in my code.

Original JSON response from the webpage:
https://www.demo.com/api/user_details/22

Response:

```
{"user_details":{"user_id":"22","username":"Test","user_email":"test@gmail.com"}}
```

I wanna scrape the `username`, `user_id` and `user_email`.

What I have tried:

```
import json
import requests
import datetime

#data outputs to a CSV file in the current directory
csv_output = open("test.csv", "w")

end_page = 5;

#scan through pages 1 to end_page for data, 20 results per page
for page in range(1,end_page+1):
    r = requests.get('https://www.demo.com/api/user_details/' + str(page))
    data = r.json()
    for index in range(len(data["user_details"])):

        csv_output.write("\"%s\",%s\n" % (data["user_details"][index]["user_id"].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))), 

        data["user_details"][index]["user_id"]

csv_output.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`data["user_details"]` is a dict and not a list and you are getting the error because you are trying to access the values using an index:

```
data["user_details"][index] ....
```

You can get the entries by accessing specific keys from the dict:

```
user_id = data["user_details"]['user_id']
username = data["user_details"]['username']
user_email = data["user_details"]['user_email']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"user_details":{"user_id":"22","username":"Test","user_email":"test@gmail.com"}}
```

User details is a dictionary here. On the other hand, `index` is an integer coming from the `range` call. The first value would be `0`. Your code tries to load `data["user_details"][0]`. But there is no key `0` in that dictionary.

To iterate over a dictionary, you can call the `items` method which would give you a tuple with `(key, value)` pair.

```
d = {"user_id":"22","username":"Test","user_email":"test@gmail.com"}
for k,v in d.items():
    print("Key: {}, Value: {}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: My code is not looping through the request. it is just showing the data in the 'd' variable.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what AKS asnwered, but I really recommend you to use [a framework called Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) tocreate crawlers. Much easier. :)

Comment: Now I'm using it more than ever. The way to go. :)